# Zend Framework Dynamic WSDL Generation and specifying SOAP Headers

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap

I'm using [Zend Framework AutoDiscovery](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.autodiscovery.html) to generate WSDL for a PHP SOAP Web Service.

I'm using a SOAP header to pass authentication information (example below).  The generated WSDL does not define the headers.

How do I get the Zend AutoDiscovery to define the soap headers in the WSDL?

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <authenticate>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>password</password>
    <authenticate>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <getData/>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do it with Zend Framework 1.*. There is a mention of an add header function for Zend Framework 2, but it is not clear to me if it will be included. I've changed my web service to pass authentication data in the body of the request